# Federated authentication with OpenIDConnect gives "Unsuccessful login with external provider"

Tags: federated-authentication, openid-connect

In my Sitecore 9.1 installation I'm trying to use Federated Authentication and have almost successfully set it up.
When I click the "log in" button on my public website I'm redirected to the `OpenIDConnect` site where I'm authenticating. I can see from Chrome Developer Tools that `OIDC` performs the postback to Sitecore with the authorization code, so the `OIDC` setup and authentication works. Sitecore, on the other hand, fails with `Unsuccessful login with external provider`.

In my log file I can see the following error:

```
4716 12:58:56 ERROR Unable to get and an external login info via Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManagerExtensions.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync. 
Most probably the identity does not have a 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' claim.
```

According to [this KB article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/252884) this is because the OIDC does not provide a `nameidentifier` claim. The OIDC provider I'm using does not send a `nameidentifier` claim, so this makes sense.

That article conveniently has a solution (#1). However, that solution doesn't work!

I've added the required `transformation` tag, but I'm still getting `Unsuccessful login with external provider`!

Here's my complete configuration file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.Enabled">
        <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.identityProviders>
        <processor type="MySolution.OidcIdentityProvider, MyAssembly" resolve="true" />
      </owin.identityProviders>
    </pipelines>
    <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
        <mapEntry name="public" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>website</site>
          </sites>
          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
            <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='MyOidc']" />
          </identityProviders>
          <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
          </externalUserBuilder>
        </mapEntry>
      </identityProvidersPerSites>
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider id="MyOidc" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>Log in with OpenIDConnect</caption>
          <icon>sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Custom/24x24/profile.png</icon>
          <domain>extranet</domain>
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
            <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
            <transformation name="Name Identifier Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="sub" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>false</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>
    </federatedAuthentication>
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProviders>
        <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer">
          <enabled>false</enabled>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>
    </federatedAuthentication>

    <sites>
      <site name="shell" set:loginPage="/sitecore/login"/>
      <site name="admin" set:loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx"/>
    </sites>

  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The article said to transform from the following source claim:

```
<sources hint="raw:AddSource">
  <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" />
</sources>
```

But seeing as I don't have a `upn` claim from OIDC either, I want to convert the `sub` claim, which is what I set up in the above configuration.

For good measure I also tried manually starting the transformation by attaching to the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`:

```
protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args) {
    args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
        Authority = "https://my.oidc",
        ClientId = "myclient",
        ClientSecret = "mysecret",
        Scope = "openid myscopes",
        RedirectUri = "https://mysite/identity/externallogincallback",
        AuthenticationType = GetAuthenticationType(),
        ResponseType = "code",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = GetAuthenticationType(),
        UseTokenLifetime = false,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
            SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated
        }
    });
}

private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context) {
    TransformationContext transformationContext = new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, GetIdentityProvider());
    context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(transformationContext);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Though this didn't help either.

The OIDC authentication and redirection obviously works, but why does Sitecore complain that identity does not have a `nameidentifier` claim when I've specifically said to transform the `sub` claim to `nameidentifier`, and how can I make this work?

**UPDATE**

After doing some more debugging I've come to the conclusion that the transform actually works. When debugging the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification and looking at the `context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity` object I can see that it now actually has the `nameidentifier` claim, as can be evidenced from this screenshot:

[image: Quickwatch]

The Sitecore log still complains with the same error, though:

```
4716 12:58:56 ERROR Unable to get and an external login info via Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManagerExtensions.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync. 
Most probably the identity does not have a 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' claim.
```

So something is obviously wrong, but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: have you confirmed the claim is actually "sub"?

Comment: @josedbaez Yes, the `sub` claim is returned in calls to `/userinfo` when I test with Postman

Comment: did you try `objectidentifier` claim?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat There is no claim called `objectidentifier` in the claims returned from `/userinfo` or on the `id_token` or `access_token`

Comment: Just to make sure, have you confirmed that the OnSecurityTokenValidated is working and the identity object does have the nameidentifier in the Claims property after calling ApplyClaimsTransformations?

Comment: [Treat it as a comment as I don't have enough reputation to add real one] Have you managed to find a solution, I'm experiencing the same issue?

Comment: @damary I haven't, but I've opened a case with Sitecore Support. I'll update this case with the answer if they manage to come up with one :)

Comment: @damary I've posted an answer. Maybe it helps for you?

Comment: Guys I am facing the same issue while trying to login through linkedin
but the difference is that I have two servers, the first one is the content management and the second one is the content delivery
login through linkedin works on content management server while on content delivery is not working
please help me... spent more than 5 days on this issue

Comment: @AmroMustafa You should probably open a new question with your specific question since yours is more related to CM/CD, while mine was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the following line in my `OidcIdentityProvider` is what was causing my problems:

```
SignInAsAuthenticationType = GetAuthenticationType(),
```

When I removed this the full authentication flow started working!
I don't know what this setting is supposed to do, but it doesn't seem to do any harm to not have it there (at least for now).

Comment: Hi GTHvidsten, I also have a the similar requirement using the OKTA provider. I am facing issue with "AuthenticationTicket" , it is coming null for. Is it possible for you the share your code with me to validate if I am missing anything. Thanks,Alok...

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue and I never had `SignInAsAuthenticationType = GetAuthenticationType(),` to begin with :worried: